# logstash file plugin no response

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to use `logstash`'s `file` plugin to read a `.csv` file.

Here is my `logstash.conf`

```
input {
    # beats {
    #   port => 5044
    # }

    # tcp {
    #   port => 5000
    # }
    # http {
    #   port => 8080
    # }
    file {
        path => "/usr/share/logs_data/train.csv"
    }
}

filter {
    csv {
        columns => ["Id","MSSubClass","MSZoning","LotFrontage"]
    }
}

output {
    # stdout {

    # }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "changeme"
        ecs_compatibility => disabled
        index => "train_2"
    }
}
```

And here is my `log`, got by `docker-compose logs logstash` (And the repo I'm using is [link](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk))

```
Attaching to docker-elk_logstash_1
logstash_1       | Using bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk
logstash_1       | OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
logstash_1       | WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
logstash_1       | WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper (file:/tmp/jruby-1/jruby5819289415785783110jopenssl.jar) to field java.security.MessageDigest.provider
logstash_1       | WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper
logstash_1       | WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
logstash_1       | WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
logstash_1       | Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:26,639][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.10.2", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.8+10 on 11.0.8+10 +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:26,733][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/queue"}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:26,774][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.dead_letter_queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue"}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:27,917][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] No persistent UUID file found. Generating new UUID {:uuid=>"7f5d3a31-2fee-4d5a-8aab-46a743ebf2ba", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/uuid"}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:29,128][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.monitoringextension.pipelineregisterhook] Internal collectors option for Logstash monitoring is deprecated and targeted for removal in the next major version.
logstash_1       | Please configure Metricbeat to monitor Logstash. Documentation can be found at: 
logstash_1       | https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring-with-metricbeat.html
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:30,241][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:31,397][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/]}}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:32,007][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/"}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:32,174][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:32,177][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:32,698][INFO ][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Monitoring License OK
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:32,700][INFO ][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Validated license for monitoring. Enabling monitoring pipeline.
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:35,877][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 57 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 23 keys and 47 values 
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:36,272][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring] Relying on default value of `pipeline.ecs_compatibility`, which may change in a future major release of Logstash. To avoid unexpected changes when upgrading Logstash, please explicitly declare your desired ECS Compatibility mode.
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:36,420][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/]}}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:36,421][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/]}}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:36,446][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/"}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:36,449][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/"}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:36,473][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:36,474][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:36,479][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:36,479][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:36,550][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//elasticsearch:9200"]}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:36,552][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchMonitoring", :hosts=>["http://elasticsearch:9200"]}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:36,590][WARN ][logstash.javapipeline    ][.monitoring-logstash] 'pipeline.ordered' is enabled and is likely less efficient, consider disabling if preserving event order is not necessary
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:36,658][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>7, :ecs_compatibility=>:disabled}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:36,722][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500, "pipeline.sources"=>["/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x77968e0c run>"}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:36,729][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][.monitoring-logstash] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>".monitoring-logstash", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>2, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>2, "pipeline.sources"=>["monitoring pipeline"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x14cd1bd7@/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:125 run>"}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:36,799][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"index_patterns"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s", "number_of_shards"=>1}, "mappings"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:38,616][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][.monitoring-logstash] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>1.88}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:38,648][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>1.92}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:38,684][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][.monitoring-logstash] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>".monitoring-logstash"}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:38,980][INFO ][logstash.inputs.file     ][main] No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the "path" setting {:sincedb_path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_11336ab8dd75b749732c8b4fc42fc297", :path=>["/usr/share/logs_data/train.csv"]}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:38,996][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:39,066][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>2, :running_pipelines=>[:main, :".monitoring-logstash"], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:39,107][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ][main][1e59759d8925d4c5eea880127ec9e48e34db99a08ccd824165795e1119380fee] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
logstash_1       | [2021-01-31T22:32:39,503][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

The thing is: I'm not being successful in using the `file` plugin, it simply doesn't work. I can work normally by using an `http` plugin, and elasticsearch is getting information, are reaching kibana. But when using `file` plugin, I get nothing.

The `file` plugin has no obligatory argument other than `path`, which I am giving correctly. So, what could be happening?

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54407824/logstash-not-reading-from-file-input), and I can guarantee that the container have access to the file. Also, here is my `docker-compose` file

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: elasticsearch
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: changeme
      # Use single node discovery in order to disable production mode and avoid bootstrap checks.
      # see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html
      discovery.type: single-node
    networks:
      - elk

  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/pipeline
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: './logstash/csv'
        target: '/usr/share/logs_data'
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5044:5044"
      - "5000:5000/tcp"
      - "5000:5000/udp"
      - "9600:9600"
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./kibana/config/kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

I have no idea how to proceed, and any clue would be helpful. Thanks =)

Comment: Are you appending data to the csv file once logstash is running? logstash skips to the end of the file when it starts. Take a look at the start_position and possibly sincedb_path options.

Comment: Badger, really tank you for this tip =)

Comment: It was good to understand how logstash deals with new files, and why in this situation we must set `start_position`  as `"beginning"`, because, as you said, by default it tries to start parsing in the end of file. It makes sense when we have one file being appended, but not if we are also adding new files in the directory that would be read! (just expanding the concept if someone would lately read this post :)  )

Comment: You're probably missing `sincedb_path`, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60428612/4604579